# Como serializar QueryDicts en DRF

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

~ Buenas, tengo la siguiente vista en mi proyecto de `DRF`

```
class CreateUsuariosAPI(APIView):
    queryset = Usuarios.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreateUsuariosSerializer
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            try:
                new_user = Usuarios.objects.create_user(**request.data)
                return Response({'new_user_id' : new_user.id}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            except:
                return Response({'error': "error_creating"}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        else:
            print(serializer.error_messages)
            return Response(BASE_SERIALIZER_ERROR_RESPONSE, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Este es su `serializer`:

```
class CreateUsuariosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photo = serializers.FileField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Usuarios
        fields = [
            "username",
            "email",
            "first_names",
            "last_names",
            "age",
            "password",
            "photo"
        ]
```

Pues bien, cuando llamo al `endpoint` que referencia a esta `vista` desde mi `frontend` usando `axios`, debo configurar la cabecera de la petición para especificar que estoy enviando archivos:

```
export async function createUsuarioAPI(data){
    const config =     {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }
    return await axios.post(BACKEND_URL+"api/create/",data, config)
}
```

El problema viene dado en que, esta configuración provoca que el `request.data` de la `vista` sea un `QueryDict` y no directamente un diccionario:

```
<QueryDict: {'username': ['juanca'], 'email': ['juanca@gmail.com'], 'first_names':      ['Juan Carlos'], 'last_names': ['Garcia Marquez'], 'age': ['18'], 'password': ['16102005 python'], 'photo[]': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 53.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

Como debería serializar los datos de manera correcta?.